# Git show diff regardless of encoding

Tags: git, utf-8, bitbucket, ascii

In bash, **git diff** doesn't show the encoding changes of UTF-8. Bitbucket shows the encoding change as follows. But, when we use **git diff** in bash, it doesn't show such change.

[image: Changes shows in bitbucket]

Is there any way to track this change using git bash commands?

Comment: Are there, perhaps, any filters?

Comment: sometimes, it might have default filters enabled. The changes also show in "gitk" gui.